# Устаревшая функция wordpress: get_woocommerce_term_meta

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В карточке товара на сайте висит такое предупреждение

> Функция get_woocommerce_term_meta с версии 3.6 считается устаревшей! Используйте get_term_meta.

Как это можно решить? Woocommerce обновлен до последней версии.

Comment: В wp-config отключить вывод ошибок define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Answer (score 1):

Это значит, что тема или плагин (не WooCommerce), используют устаревшую функцию `get_woocommerce_term_meta`. Надо найти этот код и заменить `get_woocommerce_term_meta` на `get_term_meta`. Функции принимают одинаковые аргументы, так что необходимо просто заменить название функции.